# How to move zero axis to the last position in python?

Tags: python, numpy, dimensions

How to move zero axis to the last position in python?

I tried

```
a.swapaxis(0,-1)
```

but it not only put zero axed to the end, but also put last axis to the beginning.

I tried to play with `rollaxis` but didn't understand what it does.

Comment: Do you want to move it and leave the others alone?

Comment: If `a.shape` is `(2,3,4,5)` what is the final shape?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

```
In [11]: a = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, 2)

In [12]: a
Out[12]:
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])

In [13]: a.swapaxes(0, -1)
Out[13]:
array([[[0, 4],
        [2, 6]],

       [[1, 5],
        [3, 7]]])

In [14]: np.moveaxis(a, 0, -1)
Out[14]:
array([[[0, 4],
        [1, 5]],

       [[2, 6],
        [3, 7]]])
```